# Threads in Java,can the stack with main() die/end before the stack with run()?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I were to write a main class that creates a thread, is it possible that the thread created by the class outlives the main() of the class that created it.

In a way it seems possible because, I could make the newly created thread sleep for an hour , so the new stack goes into blocked state, leaving the original main stack free for execution, the main stack executes and has nothing else to do, while the new stack is still in blocked state.

But on the other hand, there is this statement in Java that everything starts and ends with the main() method.

Please let me know which one is correct

Comment: It seems to me that trying this for yourself to see what happens would have taken you less time than typing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but only if the thread you create *isn't* a daemon thread. This (non-daemon) is actually the default.

Comment: was just typing this exact answer but you type faster!

Comment: @PeterLawrey: true; a daemon thread is free to spawn non-daemon threads, and those can keep the JVM running.

Answer (score 3):

> there is this statement in Java that everything starts and ends with the main() method.

This is not true.  You have

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

class Main {
    static {
        System.out.println("0) Printed before main");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("1) Printed in main");

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("3) Printed long after main");
            }
        });

        throw new RuntimeException() {
            public void printStackTrace(PrintStream ps) {
                System.err.println();
                System.out.println("2) Printed after main");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

prints

```
Exception in thread "main" 
0) Printed before main
1) Printed in main
2) Printed after main
3) Printed long after main
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not only possible, but the normal state of affairs when you write a Swing app.  You're not supposed to create Swing components outside the Swing thread, so the main thread queues up a task to create the UI in the Swing thread and then exits.